# hybrid cordova mobile app using HTTPS/SSL password security

Tags: ssl, https, hybrid-mobile-app

In hybrid cordova android mobile app, passing ajax call without encrypted password using https/SSL . Is it secured?

Ajax call:

```
              $.ajax({            
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: "{username:'"+user+"', password:'"+encpwd+"'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                },
                error: function (error) {

                },
             });
```

Comment: How are you passing the password specifically? As header, in the body...etc???

Comment: Please see the update with ajax call

Answer (score 1):

As long as your using SSL you should be fine. Using HTTPS the whole communication channel is encrypted client to server.